# Applying raw torques to joints in Gazebo simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, torque, actuator

I have a 7dof arm that I want to simulate, and the experiment requires me to be able to apply torques to the 7 servomotors (actuators) in the simulation. I would like to know how I can set up "actuators" in simulation so that I can apply torques to using a ROS topic.

So far, I have been able to add torque sensors to my URDF and monitor torques using sensor topics, I want to do the exact reverse of this where I can publish to set topics and have the torques be applied to the Gazebo simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [apply joint force example sdf](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/579013fe2841de68c0901192780ab8ee86cc9bb1/examples/worlds/apply_joint_force.sdf).

Comment: Did this answer your question?